# Property of a convex tangent cone

Tags: sequences-and-series, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I'm stuck at a problem concerning the tangent cone.
Let $C$ be a nonempty convex subset of $X$ and let $x \in C$.
Now show $\forall y \in C: (y-x)\in T_c(x)$.
Using the definition I have, it brings me nowhere. $Y \in T_c(x)$ if and only if there exist sequences $(\alpha_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converging to $0$ with all $\alpha_n\geq 0$ and $(y_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ with $y_n \text{ converging to } y$ and $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}: x+\alpha_n y_n$. Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result is showing something quite geometric, and it is represented in the picture in the end of my answer. By taking the closure of such tangent directions, It shows that the tangent cone contains the translated convex set. In order to show this, let $x$ be a point in $C$. Now, Let $y$ be another point in $C$. We have that, by the definition of a convex set, $$x+ s (y-x) = (1-s) x + s y \in C,$$ for every $0 \leq s \leq 1$. Letting, $s_k = 1/k$, for every $k$ we have that $$x+ s_k (y-x) = (1-s_k) x + s_k y \in C,$$ for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$, since $0 \leq s_k \leq 1.$ This shows your result.

[image]